# Learn from my mistake

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question "[What is the spin connection in 9 dimensions as opposed to 5 dimensions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226120/what-is-the-spin-connection-in-9-dimensions-as-opposed-to-5-dimensions?noredirect=1#comment558359_226120)" received two down votes. I would like to know what I can do to improve the quality of this question. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvotes either.

Comment: The question seems reasonable to me and I gave an upvote. Can those who think it's not good tell what's wrong?

Comment: I did not downvote and hadn't even seen the question and would have ignored it if I did. But my guess is that the tags are wrong (commutative algebra??) and it's not clear (to me at least) that this is even math. Looks like physics to me. Shouldn't it be in physics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @FelipeVoloch I edited the tags. Despite the presentation which has a "physicist's accent", I think this is comfortably within the ambit of pure mathematics, and certainly there are MO users who could answer (e.g., it's likely Sebastian Goette could).

Comment: Don't worry about a few downvotes.  Maybe somebody just hates Linux...  If every downvote triggered a Meta question, we would be overwhelmed here.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Or they hate Lynyrd Skynyrd :)

Comment: I did not downvote either. I see two possible reasons: 1. the notation looks more like physics than maths (see @FelipeVoloch's comment). 2. for someone working with spinors, the question may look a little too elementary. Although I am rather new here, I've seen two different attitudes: one, where all elementary questions are redirected to math.stackexchange, if possible. And another one, where elementary questions whose solutions are not common knowledge are welcome. And I think that your question falls in that category (elementary, but the answer is more or less hidden in the literature).